# How to change the default home directory in oh my zsh terminal?

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am working to install oh my zsh on my system and its working fine. The home directory is automatically set to what I need i.e. `#( 08/05/21@ 5:22PM )( asus@LAPTOP-DVFCDSAR ):/mnt/c/Users/asus`

Initially it was in `~` directory. To change to the directory of my computer system I wrote `export CDPATH=~/mnt/c/Users/asus` in Windows Terminal set up to use Ubuntu from wsl.

But now when I set up Hyper Terminal to use oh my zsh, the default directory is still `~` which is `/home/asus/`. And now if I had to change to the directory I want, I need to `cd` to asus directory. How do I change this behaviour of hyper terminal to automatically use the above path to `asus` as default directory whenever I open hyper terminal?

Comment: You can use `usermod` to change an account's home directory.

Comment: @VivekKumar: Each user has **one** home directory (you can not have a default one and optionally some others). The home directory is unrelated to a shell, let alone to an application package running in the shell such as oh-my-zsh. It is not clear to me, what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @user1934428 Hey, I'm sorry for the confusion. My request is simple, when I open my hyperjs terminal, the default directory (the directory in which I am then) is `~` which is `home/asus/`. I have enables WSL for ubuntu. Now every time I need to access my files (which are stored in C drive or Desktop) I have to type `cd /mnt/c/Users/asus/`. This is quite irritating because I have to do this every time I open a terminal. Now, I ask of you, can I change this `~` from `home/asus/` to -> `/mnt/c/Users/asus` .

Comment: @Shawn: How should I do that? I have already made a user and now want to change the default directory of user as explained to >user1934428

Comment: @VivekKumar: In this case, the most natural solution would be to put this `cd` statement into your `.zshrc`. Fiddling with your HOME directory is something unrelated to zsh, and relates in your case only to the usage of WSL. I don't know if you can do this in the context of WSL, and in any case **this** should be asked then in [so], not here.